# Compare 2 arrays and find an attribute's value from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays mentioned below.

```
const arr1 = [{ Id: "a153O000001mjD1QAI", Document_ID__c: 176767 }];


const arr2 = [
  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176767",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    response_type: ["General"],
    size: 70953,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127462",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED FOR USE",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127461",
    major_version_number: "2",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED ,MINOR CHANGES",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_answer: "Dosage",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176776",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "General Info Test 2",
    response_type: ["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],
    size: 25432,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "General Info Test 2",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },
];
```

I want to search the value of attribute 'Document_ID__c' from arr1 in arr2 and if it matches '176767' on any element in arr2,
just create a new array and store that element.

For e.g my desired output is

```
const finalarray = [
  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176767",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    response_type: ["General"],
    size: 70953,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },
];
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: I cannot read your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [{ Id: "a153O000001mjD1QAI", Document_ID__c: 176767 }];


const arr2 = [
  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176767",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    response_type: ["General"],
    size: 70953,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127462",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED FOR USE",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127461",
    major_version_number: "2",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED ,MINOR CHANGES",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_answer: "Dosage",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176776",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "General Info Test 2",
    response_type: ["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],
    size: 25432,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "General Info Test 2",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },
];

let finalArray = [];

arr1.forEach(ar1 => finalArray.push(arr2.filter(ar2 => +ar2.id ===ar1.Document_ID__c)));

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let mArray = []


for (i in arr1) {
    for (j in arr2){
      if (arr1[i].Document_ID__c == arr2[j].id) {
         mArray.push(arr2[j])
      }
    }
}

console.log(mArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This :

```
const arr1 = [{ Id: "a153O000001mjD1QAI", Document_ID__c: 176767 }];


const arr2 = [
  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176767",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    response_type: ["General"],
    size: 70953,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127462",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED FOR USE",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127461",
    major_version_number: "2",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED ,MINOR CHANGES",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },

  {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_answer: "Dosage",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176776",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "General Info Test 2",
    response_type: ["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],
    size: 25432,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "General Info Test 2",
    type: "Medical Information",
  },
];

var newObj = arr1.map(j =>{
  return  arr2.filter(e=>{
       return e.id == j.Document_ID__c
   })
})
 console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const finalArray = arr2.filter((a) => arr1.some((b) => a.id == b.Document_ID__c));
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const arr1 = [{ Id: "a153O000001mjD1QAI", Document_ID__c: 176767 }];

const arr2 = [{
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176767",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    response_type: ["General"],
    size: 70953,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "Advance Search Doc_General Information",
    type: "Medical Information",
}, {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127462",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED FOR USE",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
}, {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "127461",
    major_version_number: "2",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "APPROVAL verdict APPROVED ,MINOR CHANGES",
    response_type: ["Administration"],
    size: 1362339,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "ahsdjhsahdasld",
    type: "Medical Information",
}, {
    classification: "Scientific Response",
    core_san_answer: "Dosage",
    core_san_localization_translation: ["No"],
    core_san_verbal_only: "false",
    id: "176776",
    major_version_number: "1",
    minor_version_number: "0",
    name: "General Info Test 2",
    response_type: ["Pharmacokinetics and Pharmacodynamics"],
    size: 25432,
    subtype: "Local",
    title: "General Info Test 2",
    type: "Medical Information",
}];

const result = arr2.filter((a) => arr1.some((b) => a.id.toString() === b.Document_ID__c.toString()));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using the [Array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) built into JS is fine for this:

```
var result = arr2.filter(function(o1){
    // filter out  items in result2
    return arr1.some(function(o2){
        return o1['id'] == o2['Document_ID__c']; 
    });
    });
```